# MsBuild 1.5.3 doesn't generate zip file

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have a command:

```
  msbuild.exe MyProject.sln /nologo /p:PackageLocation="C:\Some\Path\package" 
  /p:OutDir="C:\Some\Path\out" /p:DeployOnBuild=true 
  /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:configuration="Release" 
  /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="C:\Some\Path\package\package.zip"
```

And the problem is that on my local machine it works fine, but when i do the same script on production server, the build finished success too but there is no package.zip file.

The versions of VS are the same, but MsBuild's versions are different.

Local (15.1.1012)

Server (15.3.409)

Comment: Maybe the user running the script on the Server does not have sufficient privileges to write in that Directory. you could try running the script as Administrator or changing the DesktopBuildPackageLocation path to the user's home directory

Comment: @GuyMontag i tried to do it with user's home directory, nothing changed and this seems weird, cuz "out" folder with build result appeared in both cases

Comment: Okay, try running it with `/consoleloggerparameters:Summary /verbosity:detailed`. 
This should give you some detailed messeges if any warnings occur during build. Remove any personal information, if there is any, and share the results here.